# Grouping and Offset

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I want to be able to group a number of values in a column by matching  there first n characters where n is the lengh-2

So for 123456 the length is 6 so trying to find a match for the first 4 characters in the cell above.

example below shows  Column `A` with the list of values and the column `B` is my desired results.

Hopefully this makes sense..

```
A           B
RTL1162 | 
123456  | 
RTL2051 | RTL2051
RTL2052 | RTL2051
RTL2050 | RTL2051
121213  | 
RTL9051 | RTL9051
RTL9052 | RTL9051
RTL9050 | RTL9051
```

I was trying to achieve this using OFFSET but the result is that its only looking at the one 1 row above and I want it to group them all until it doesn't match the first n characters.

```
=IF(LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-2)= (LEFT(OFFSET(A1, -1,0,1,1), LEN(Sheet1!A1)-2)), A1, A2)
```

Comment: Unless you have a problem specifically related to a programming question, you'd probably be better asking this in another forum like SuperUser.com.

Comment: I thought it was specific programming related question/problem?!

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler This is borderline but probably on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list of data is in colA (from **A2** down), you can enter this in B2 and drag down to fill

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),B1,A2)
```

Comment: Simple, thanks alot!! I didn't need the offset at all!!

Comment: On a slightly different note If I wanted to not display any singular results would this be easy to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "not display any singular results"?

Comment: I.e. if the value in column b is unique don't display it

Comment: Can you update your question, and add a "column C" to show what you mean ?

Comment: I've updated the Column B above... Ideally the results would be in column b only...

Comment: Its ok I've fixed this, I've added a check for for duplicates in a column which solves this.. Thanks for your help starting this off

Answer (score 0):

In `B1` enter:

```
=A1
```

In `B2` enter:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)=LEFT(B1,LEN(A2)-2),B1,A2)
```

Fill down.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but This produces a circular reference error...

Comment: Ah, sorry! I created this in rows 2 and 3 and forgot to transpose the latter formula to your case.